# Plotting two lines in a ggplot graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe as given below:  I am trying to plot count and col.count as two lines in a ggplot graph.  I don't seem to get this right.  Appreciate any help.

```
month   count   col.count
=============================
16-05-May   1       1154688 
16-06-Jun   1       1092764 
16-07-Jul   2       1060445 
16-08-Aug   19      1092050 
16-09-Sep   173     1041299 
16-10-Oct   1469    1261100 
16-11-Nov   1819    1356139 
16-12-Dec   1263    1272486 
17-01-Jan   748     1170097 
17-02-Feb   684     1016672
```

Thank you.

Comment: The difference in magnitude between the two variables is going to make the count line appear almost flat.

Comment: I tried with log(count) and log(col.count) too.  Looking more at the relative difference than the actual count value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of numbers in both columns are magnitudes off so may want to plot using a log scale on y-axis. Here's how to plot two variables using ggplot on the same graph in R.

```
# first parse date string into Date object
df$date <- as.Date(df$month, "%y-%d-%b") # 16-05-May

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(date)) + scale_y_log10() +
  geom_line(aes(y = count, colour = "red")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = col.count, colour = "blue"))
```

If you normalize the *col.count* variable as you describe then you can plot them together without one appearing completely flat with respect to the other.

```
library(scales)
ggplot(df, aes(date)) + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)  +
  geom_line(aes(y = count, colour = "red")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = col.count/2000, colour = "blue"))
```

[image: two plots on same graph]

Showing the two graphs as time series stacked on each other is another approach to show two variables that have vastly different ranges on y-axis.

```
require(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(date,count)) + geom_line(colour = "red") 
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(date,col.count)) + geom_line(colour = "blue") 
grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow=2)
```

[image: Two graphs stacked on each other with same x-axis]

Comment: The first solution is what I was looking for.  I also made a scale adjustment by dividing col.count/2000.  This way, I could make it work.  Thank you very much.